# Array Value Decreasing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I Use the following Code to choose the correct answer and when it reaches the limit it shows the Result View,

```
-(void)displayImageAndButton:(int)pos
{
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[animage.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
animage.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[imageary objectAtIndex:pos]]];
//NSLog(@"pos value%d",pos);
UIView *newView = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    NSLog(@"pos value%d",pos);
    UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
    name=[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++];
    [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
newView = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    NSLog(@"pos value%d",pos);
    UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
    name=[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++];
    [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
newView = [self.view viewWithTag:3];
if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    NSLog(@"pos value%d",pos);
    UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
    name=[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++];
    [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
newView = [self.view viewWithTag:4];
if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    NSLog(@"pos value%d",pos);
    UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
    name=[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++];// Here the problem coming when it value 13 its getting error what should i change
    [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

}
```

Update ^^^

```
- (IBAction)submitGuess:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([mybutton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:[imageary objectAtIndex:positionOfQuest]])
    {
        //titles equal
        [self alertshow];
        positionOfQuest++;
        totalGuesses++;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeImageView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [self displayImageAndButton:positionOfQuest];
        [lb1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question %i ", positionOfQuest + 1]];
    } else {
        totalGuesses++;
        [self alertshow2];
    }

    NSLog(@"toatguess value%d",positionOfQuest);
    NSLog(@"toatguess value%d",numCorrect);
    if(positionOfQuest==numCorrect)
    {
        [self resulmsg];
        [lb3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i guesses, %.02f%% correct", totalGuesses,
                      1000 / (float)totalGuesses]];

        [lb4 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.02f%%",1000 / (float)totalGuesses]];
        NSLog(@"lb4%@",lb4);
    }
}
```

I'm having limit of 10, ie. numcorrect value is 10. But while it reaches 9 it shows error.

```
2012-11-28 15:27:56.430 Kidsapp[4225:c07] toatguess value8
2012-11-28 15:27:56.431 Kidsapp[4225:c07] toatguess value10
2012-11-28 15:27:57.409 Kidsapp[4225:c07] toatguess value9
2012-11-28 15:27:57.409 Kidsapp[4225:c07] toatguess value10
2012-11-28 15:27:58.017 Kidsapp[4225:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 13 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]'
```

What is the error here?

Comment: Can you tell a little more about the error. What is the error you get? Where exactly do you get it? Can you paste some log output?

Comment: Please post your error message to get a better view of your problem.

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid Pls check I updated my quest with code

Comment: problem in this [imageary objectAtIndex:positionOfQuest]

Comment: Really Rajneesh? If I look at the log it suggests that next the positionOfQuest would hold a value of 10, while we are looking for the value 13. It might well be in another chunk of code, or the positionOfQuest variable gets updated somewhere else, but the other output suggests that it steps nicely with increments of 1.

Comment: Just do one thing if ([imageary count > positionOfQuest]) then write your code..

Comment: how much object do you have in imageary

Comment: starting at 0 based index can solve your problem because in this way the extra element will be automatically will be pointed at your last. As you can see the 13th object of array of 12 can fix the problem.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 NO i added the code as per yur comment but still its showing the same error.

Comment: what is pos... and what id the value of pos when its getting eerror

Comment: @Rajneesh071  pos is showing the title to the button from array., when the pos value reached 13 its showing the error

Comment: is your imageAry always contain 12 object....or its changes...???

Comment: it doesn change it contains 12 objects only

Comment: so just do   if(pos <13){ then call this function -(void)displayImageAndButton:(int)pos }

Comment: @Rajneesh071 the pos is being intialized in `-(void)displayImageAndButton:(int)pos` <- Here only then how? i will do  if(pos <13){}

Comment: when and where are you calling this function..?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as for your error, it clear that you are trying to access the 13th object of your array of 12. Try to put some breakpoints to debug your code.

Comment: Use a few breakpoints in your code and then step through the execution so you can see exactly where the error occurs. Once you know where it occurs you can find out which value reaches 13 while it should not and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Array starts with index 0 so the your maximum index value mustbe [[array count]-1].
As per your code positionOfQuest is getting value 13 you got error

because your array count is 13 but the index of array  is 0 from 12.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `positionOfQuest` is getting value 13 and you are searching

```
[imageary objectAtIndex:12];
```

But imageary have object till index 12 (Total 13 object index 0....12)

So according to your problem just make an if condition like

```
if ([imageary count] > positionOfQuest)
{
    if ([mybutton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:[imageary objectAtIndex:positionOfQuest]])
    {
        //Your work
    }

}
```

Comment: i update the code and i find where it crashes,ther commented..But what should i change over their